# Merge Button Actions to reduce duplication

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, code-duplication

I have the present code to allow selection of the days of the week for a repeating event. At present they are independent, and the duplication is high.

How can the buttons be refactored to reduce duplication?

```
// Array of days repeating:
    var weekDayRepeat = [false,false,false,false,false,false,false]

    var savedEventId : String = ""

    @IBOutlet weak var datePickerStart: UIDatePicker!

    @IBOutlet weak var datePickerEnd: UIDatePicker!

    @IBOutlet weak var repeatSwitch: UISwitch!

    @IBOutlet weak var monSelect: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var tuesSelect: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var wedsSelect: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var thursSelect: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var friSelect: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var satSelect: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var sunSelect: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var repeatingLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func monSelect(sender: AnyObject) {
        if(weekDayRepeat[0]) {
            monSelect.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGrayColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            weekDayRepeat[0] = false

        } else {
            monSelect.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            weekDayRepeat[0] = true

        }

    }

    @IBAction func tuesSelect(sender: AnyObject) {
        if(weekDayRepeat[1]) {
            tuesSelect.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGrayColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            weekDayRepeat[1] = false

        } else {
            tuesSelect.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            weekDayRepeat[1] = true

        }
    }

    @IBAction func wedsSelect(sender: AnyObject) {
        if(weekDayRepeat[2]) {
            wedsSelect.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGrayColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            weekDayRepeat[2] = false

        } else {
            wedsSelect.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            weekDayRepeat[2] = true

        }
    }

    @IBAction func thursSelect(sender: AnyObject) {
        if(weekDayRepeat[3]) {
            thursSelect.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGrayColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            weekDayRepeat[3] = false

        } else {
            thursSelect.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            weekDayRepeat[3] = true

        }
    }

    @IBAction func friSelect(sender: AnyObject) {
        if(weekDayRepeat[4]) {
            friSelect.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGrayColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            weekDayRepeat[4] = false

        } else {
            friSelect.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            weekDayRepeat[4] = true

        }

    }

    @IBAction func satSelect(sender: AnyObject) {
        if(weekDayRepeat[5]) {
            satSelect.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGrayColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            weekDayRepeat[5] = false

        } else {
            satSelect.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            weekDayRepeat[5] = true

        }
    }

    @IBAction func sunSelect(sender: AnyObject) {
        if(weekDayRepeat[6]) {
            sunSelect.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGrayColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            weekDayRepeat[6] = false

        } else {
            sunSelect.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            weekDayRepeat[6] = true

        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set initial conditions of the page...:
        repeatSwitch.on = true

        datePickerStart.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Time
        datePickerEnd.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Time

        monSelect.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGrayColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        tuesSelect.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGrayColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        wedsSelect.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGrayColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        thursSelect.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGrayColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        friSelect.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGrayColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        satSelect.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGrayColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        sunSelect.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGrayColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)


        // Allow dynamically changing the mode given if repeating or not.
        // If switch to repeating, then show selecting only the time and list of days to select/multi-select
        repeatSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.switchChanged(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

### try the following code :

```
@IBOutlet var weekDayBtns: [UIButton]!

@IBAction func weekDayBtnAction(sender: UIButton) {

    weekDayRepeat[sender.tag] = !weekDayRepeat[sender.tag]
    sender.setTitleColor(weekDayRepeat[sender.tag] ? UIColor.blackColor():UIColor.lightGrayColor()  , forState: UIControlState.Normal)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    weekDayBtns.forEach({$0.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGrayColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)})
}
```

1. create an `IBOutlet Collection`:  `@IBOutlet var weekDayBtns: [UIButton]!`
2. create an general `IBAction` :`@IBAction func weekDayBtnAction(sender: UIButton){}`
3. connect the btns all to `IBOutlet Collection` and `IBAction`
4. set the btn tag

### here are screenshots：

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Sauron:   One possible solution would be the following...
if each button is given a number as its title, you could replicate the technique used to make a simple calculator, where by...

1. the first button is used to create IBAction / func (kept as uibutton)
2. Subsequent buttons are then Control-dragged to the "ViewController" in the hierarchy in 'document outline' for the storyboard
3. When the popup shows. Go to the middle, under "sent events" which should have the name of the first button function you created
4. Do the same for all the other buttons

This helps to reduce duplication of the code writing. The buttons can then later be identified by their Title. E.g.

```
@IBAction func numberTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    let nameOfDay = sender.currentTitle
```

}

Thus allowing you to utilise the weekday elsewhere within the code.
Found a youtube link that may help you quickly re: the duplication...?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NJHsdjH2HdY